# Ambiguous buck converter schematic in the datasheet

Tags: buck

I'm building a PCB to work with USB-C PD as power source. I'm planning to use CYPD3177 as a controller to negotiate 12V. As far as I understood I need to add a buck converter into the power line to supply 3V3 to the controller (also planning to use it for the main MCU). I didn't want to take a readily available buck converter module so I'm trying to implement it on the PCB. I figured I could use MP1484 (have used modules based on that regulator before) so I'm looking at the schematics available in the data sheet here https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MP1484-1186021.pdf. Here is what it suggests:

[image: schematic from the data sheet]

I got confused by couple things there:

- C1 appears to be polarized as it has an arc and is different from the rest on the schematic (even though it is missing + sign). But it says ceramic which as I understand means unpolarized. From the location of it it appears to be used as a decoupling capacitor so I think it should be unpolarised. Is there something Is there something I'm missing there and could there be a reason for it to use a different symbol?
- C2 says x2 next to it. Since it is also a decoupling capacitor, should I assume it means two 10uF caps should be placed in parallel there?

UPDATE1
after reading CYPD3177 documentation more closely it seems I don't necessarily need an external buck converter to power it as it can use internal LDO. However I still need a buck converter to power other stuff. It is also probably still a good idea to use the converter to power CYPD3177 because internally it relies on LDO while the main line will be 12V.

Comment: The curved symbol has historically been used for nonpolar capacitors as well, the asymmetry denoting outside foil perhaps. I use these symbols myself, and always place a '+' to specify polarization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something Is there something I'm missing there and could there be a reason for it to use a different symbol?

This could be a stock diagram that was used and the symbol not changed. A polarized capacitor is sometimes used in this position. Just use the ceramic as indicated. When drawing your own diagram, use the correct symbol.

> C2 says x2 next to it. Since it is also a decoupling capacitor, should I assume it means two 10uF caps should be placed in parallel there?

Yes,it means two capacitors in parallel. This technique is used to decrease ESR and ESL. Or if the desired value is not available then two in parallel works.

C1 might be considered a decoupling capacitor, but may be required for stable operation of the converter as well.

C2 is not a decoupling capacitor. It is required for the operation of the buck converter while also reducing output ripple.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response

>C2 is not a decoupling capacitor. It is required for the operation of the buck converter while also reducing output ripple.

hmm, I thought that was the name of pretty much any capacitor put across power lines, guess I need to do some research on the topic, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

The symbol for C1 does suggest a polarised device but you’re right that ceramic caps aren’t polarised.  I think the intention is that you could use an electrolytic here but a ceramic cap would also work.  And yes, the x2 for C2 does suggest using two caps in parallel.  I’d agree that if you’re going to use a. Pick converter then you might as well not use the LDO at all, provided that the buck converter can operate from 5V while the 12V is negotiated.

Comment: thanks for the response!